# Linux Mint Disks shows 0.0 KB allocated to partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, linux-mint

I know I'm supposed to have no free space and I should have 12 GB root partition and around 100 GB home. But this happened after I tried to allocate more space to my root partition by shrinking my home partition. Please help. My root is running out of space and I'd like to extend by around 10 GB

[image]

Comment: These rectangles in the screenshot are not *hard* data. Please [edit] and post the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`. Did you mess with your drive from within the OS booted from the drive itself? or from some live CD/DVD/USB Linux?

Comment: `lsblk` or `mount | grep /dev/sd` or `mount | grep "on / "` might be helpful too, or everything from `mount`